# Perform Calculations on GPU in Java

Tags: java, performance, opengl, gpu

I'm looking to see if there's a way one can make part of a Java program, specifically the need for many repeated, slightly complex calculations, execute on a computer's GPU rather than solely on the CPU. I know that libraries like LWJGL allow Java programs to utilize the GPU, but I've not found a straightforward way to simply perform calculations on it that are not necessarily related to graphics.

Is there a way to, for example speed up the following code using a computer's GPU?

```
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double x;
    for(int i=0; i < 1080; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<1920; j++){
            x = Math.sqrt(Math.tan(1d - Math.sin(i * j)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
```

When I test the above, solely-CPU operated, function, it takes about 1.25 seconds for it to complete.

Comment: Look into OpenCL, there are bindings for Java: http://www.jocl.org/

Comment: Will OpenCL only work for AMD/Nvidia GPUs?

Comment: Yes, as long as the drivers support it (which most should). It's a cross platform API and it's not limited to GPUs (it can seamlessly fallback to CPU execution for the same code if there's no GPU for example).

Comment: No! OpenCL runs on CPUs, Intel Xeon Phi, other GPUs besides AMD/NVIDIA, all the way to FPGAs.

Comment: Why GPU? Running native C code on the CPU will be much faster. Try JNI to C.

Comment: @Jeff: OP's problem is massively parallel. Essentially a two dimensional array with dimensions 1920×1080 (that's FullHD image extents), where each element does depend only on the position and a constant factor. This is something GPUs do without breaking into a sweat, leaving *every* CPU in the dust.

Comment: @datenwolf You have no idea what you're talking about. Data parallelism across threads and SIMD will do just fine here. Dual-socket Intel Haswell does 1.3 TF/s with completely portable OpenMP 4 code.

Comment: @Jeff: Well, that 1.3TF/s figure takes a lot of freedoms in interpreting it. Also to achieve it, you have to use a dual socket motherboard (expensive) and the fastest variant of the CPU (even more expensive). Now compare this with a NVidia GeForce 950, the current generation midrange level GPU, goes over the counter for far less than 1/3 of the price of one of the two required Haswel CPUs. And then there's of course the topic of memory bandwidth. The top Haswell CPU has some 100GiB/s total memory bandwidth. That's where entry level GPUs start.

Comment: @datenwolf GeForce 950 is crippled for double precision, so I don't think it's a reasonable comparison.  As for bandwidth, how fast can you push bytes across PCI gen 3 again?

Comment: @Jeff: Some 15GiB/s go over PCI-E gen 3. However once you're on the GPU memory, you've got to work with orders of magnitude more of it. Admittedly OP's code uses double precision. Okay, then I suggest using an AMD Radeon Volcanic Islands entry level GPU – those *can* do double precision. While we're at the topic: It's absolutely shamefull that no implementation of the Intel architecture implements a memory-to-memory DMA engine. I'm currently working on a problem, where the single core memory bandwidth for copy operations is a real show stopper.

Comment: @Jeff: Zero copy doesn't do the trick, because this is pinned DMA memory, which takes too long to setup for a transfer. Oh, maybe I should mention, that for a living I develop realtime 4D OCT software, where a uninterrupted, continuous stream of some 6GiB/s of data is processed. Easy enough to do with GPUs, the bottleneck we're running into is single core memory bandwidth. Using multiple threads doesn't cut it either, because the whole management overhead and latencies throw a wrench into the gears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91782/discussion-between-jeff-and-datenwolf).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [aparapi](https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi). Other than that any Java wrappers around native OpenCL/CUDA might be useful.

Comment: I've tried using aparapi, but whenever I try to use it for anything(eg multiplying two values one million times), the CPU does it much faster than the Kernel does

Comment: As of today Aparapi is abandoned and it never was quite stable.